# Generate ppsx thumbnail using php

Tags: php, pdf, powerpoint, thumbnails

I try to generate a thumbnail for a `PPSX` file, I do it with pdf files and it works perfectly using `Spatie\PdfToImage` library.

I search a lot about `PPSX` version but there's no library to do it.

I try to convert `PPSX` to a `pdf` using `PHP` file but with the same issue, no solution on the internet.

is there any solution to do it?

Comment: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation found this, maybe helps? (source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3137886/5300921)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Aspose.Slides Cloud SDK for PHP](https://products.aspose.cloud/slides/php/) to convert a Slide Show file and other presentation files to images and many other formats. The following code example shows you how to convert slides from a `PPSX` file to `PNG` images:

```php
use Aspose\Slides\Cloud\Sdk\Api\Configuration;
use Aspose\Slides\Cloud\Sdk\Api\SlidesApi;

$configuration = new Configuration();
$configuration->setAppSid("my_client_id");
$configuration->setAppKey("my_client_key");

$slidesApi = new SlidesApi(null, $configuration);

// Open a Slide Show file.
$fileStream = fopen("example.ppsx", 'r');

// Select slides to convert to images (all slides by default).
$slideIndices = array(1, 3);

// Convert the slides to PNG images, for example.
$response = $slidesApi->convert($fileStream, "png", null, null, null, $slideIndices);

// Save the result (zip file with the images) to a local file path.
$fileSize = $response->getSize();
$contents = $response->fread($fileSize);
file_put_contents("example_images.zip", $contents);
```

Sometimes it is necessary to convert a presentation to another format without any code. In such a case, you can use the [Online Presentation Converter](https://products.aspose.app/slides/conversion).

I work as a Support Developer at Aspose.